# Is there a way to limit the number of test workers on AppVeyor?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, appveyor

In the logs it says that 2 test workers were used, is there a way to configure max to be 1?

```
Run Settings
    ...
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 2
```

Using a manual script like below works but gets messy when the solution contains many assemblies.

```
test_script:
  - nunit3-console.exe Gu.Persist.Core.Tests\bin\Release\Gu.Persist.Core.Tests.dll --result=myresults.xml;format=AppVeyor --workers=1
  - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

AppVeyor generates `nunit3-console` command line without any `--workers` switch. I believe that number of workers is decided by nunit console itself. As I understand if you remove [Parallelizable Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute) from your tests, it will be only one worker.

Comment: I tried that  but it did not solve my issue. I suspect that two processes are used for running the tests but not sure. I ended up writing a hack taking a lock on a file :)